# How to check admin associates to which store in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have created few stores and created different admins for each store. Now I want to get the admin details with their store ID. Currently I am using the given code:

```
$sess_data = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getData();
$detail = $sess_data['user']->getData();
print_r($detail);
```

Result:

```
[user_id] => 3
[firstname] => name
[lastname] => last
[email] => mss.name@gmail.com
[username] => store2
[password] => 7fa6d16a7d9892479966dde026724294:CWKkyKBp7drPnfmlJvIUxpP00J4DzPKr
[created] => 2014-10-20 22:28:49
[modified] => 2014-10-20 06:51:32
[logdate] => 2014-10-21 04:28:49
[lognum] => 6
[reload_acl_flag] => 0
[is_active] => 1
[extra] => 
[rp_token] => 
[rp_token_created_at] =>
```

My question is how can I get the Store ID associated with that admin account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepak, As per my knowledge Magento doesn't have this functionality in community and Enterprise edition also. I have worked both. You can create multiple store and multiple admin users, but you can't assign a user for a particular store. I don't know how did u say this..

```
// Gets the current store's details
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

// Gets the current store's id
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

// Gets the current store's code
$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();

// Gets the current website's id
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

// Gets the current store's group id
$storeGroupId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getGroupId();

// Gets the current store's name
$storeName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

// Gets the current store's sort order
$storeSortOrder = Mage::app()->getStore()->getSortOrder();

// Gets the current store's status
$storeIsActive = Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive();

// Gets the current store's locale
$storeLocaleCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getLocaleCode();

// Gets the current store's home url
$storeHomeUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getHomeUrl();
```

And you can get admin user session by this,

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
```